# Renaming folders in Arduino Uno' SD card

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, sd-card

I want to rename folders through the SD shield but it does not rename them, because It renames It in another default name 
How Can i rename it using the name that I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this post (https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=73265.0) this library should be able to rename the folders (https://github.com/greiman?tab=repositories) but there are a lot of posts out there saying they are having problems.

It might be worth checking you can rename them on a PC, there may be problems with name lengths etc that will just complicate matters.

Comment: It looks like all of the problems mentioned in the forum.arduino.cc post are due to the obtuse asker insisting on keeping duplicative calls to the obsolete SD.h wrapper alongside using SdFAT for renaming.  In other words, all self-inflicted problems.